# Difference between unicode cdot and * in julia

Tags: julia

I've started using the unicode cdot in place of * in my Julia code because I find it easier to read.  I thought they were the same, but apparently there is a difference I don't understand.  Is there documentation on this?

```
julia> 2pi⋅(0:1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching dot(::Float64, ::UnitRange{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  dot(::Number, ::Number) at linalg\generic.jl:301
  dot{T<:Union{Float32,Float64},TI<:Integer}(::Array{T<:Union{Float32,Float64},1}, ::Union{Range{TI<:Integer},UnitRange{TI<:Integer}}, ::Array{T<:Union{Float32,Float64},1}, ::Union{Range{TI<:Integer},UnitRange{TI<:Integer}}) at linalg\matmul.jl:48
  dot{T<:Union{Complex{Float32},Complex{Float64}},TI<:Integer}(::Array{T<:Union{Complex{Float32},Complex{Float64}},1}, ::Union{Range{TI<:Integer},UnitRange{TI<:Integer}}, ::Array{T<:Union{Complex{Float32},Complex{Float64}},1}, ::Union{Range{TI<:Integer},UnitRange{TI<:Integer}}) at linalg\matmul.jl:61
  ...

julia> 2pi*(0:1)
0.0:6.283185307179586:6.283185307179586
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dot` or `⋅` is not the same as multiplication (`*`). You can find out what it's for by typing `?dot`:

```
help?> ⋅
search: ⋅

  dot(x, y)
  ⋅(x,y)

  Compute the dot product. For complex vectors, the first vector is conjugated. [...]
```

For more info about the dot product, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: DNF beat me by 4 min! but thanks for pointing out the documentation, I forgot about that

Comment: I was using the documentation here (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/The_REPL).  I had seen the documentation you're showing but was confused.  I might have been thinking it would work both as a dot product and regular multiplication, which it does until you mix scalars with other types.

Comment: @Todd if you want to find all of the applicable methods that work with an operator, then call `methods` on it, e.g. `methods(*)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are conflating two different operators. The cdot aliases the `dot` function, while the asterisk `*` aliases multiplication routines.

I suspect that you want to do a dot product. The error that you see tells you that Julia does not know how to compute the dot product of a scalar floating point number (`Float64`) with an integer unit range (`UnitRange{Int}`). If you think about it, using `dot` here makes little sense.

In contrast, the second command `2pi*(0:1)` computes the product of a scalar against the same `UnitRange` object. That simply rescales the range, and Julia has a method to do that.

A few options for you, depending on what you want to do:

1. Use `*` instead of `dot` here (easiest)
2. Code your own `dot` method to handle rescaling of `UnitRange` objects (probably not helpful)
3. Use elementwise multiplication `.*` (careful, not equal to `dot`!)